# Run mongodb in node.js without run mongod

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I just want to run a Mongodb server inside node.js with this

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var client = new Db('pixgalery00002', new Server('127.0.0.1', 27017, {}), {safe:false});

 for (var i ; i = i; i) {

   client.open(function(err, pClient) {

   if (err) throw err;

  });

 }
```

When I was using Mac OS X Lion, this worked. But today I upgraded to Mountain Lion, and suddenly, this doesn't work! I have to run `mongod` if I want to use mongodb, but I don't want that! Is a problem of mongodb in Mountain Lion? Any solution for this...?

I was using connect-mongodb as session store, but now it doesn't work too!

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but don't you need the db server running in order to connect to it?

Comment: @chovy Technically, with this piece of code is running. This code was working to me without running mongod, but today that I updated to Mountain Lion, suddenly this code doesn't works!

Comment: you probably are still running mongod in the background. Maybe the startup script changed. Check brew mongodb page or file an issue there.

Comment: I checked that and I change the code properly, but it stills no working.

Comment: One thing I had to do was set `verbose = true` in the mongodb configuration file and then tail the log file on mac. It wasn't until I did that, did I discover I had a permission problem. and Mongod needed to be started as root, which I wasn't doing.